Travis CI: env variable is empty when read from shell script
I have set some global variables in the Travis CI settings UI.
I've been trying to solve this on and off for a while, but if I recall correctly it stopped working in May this year (last time the pypi token was used).
When I try to echo the variable, I get an empty output: https://app.travis-ci.com/github/blockchain-certificates/cert-schema/jobs/627323874#L845-L846, and later https://app.travis-ci.com/github/blockchain-certificates/cert-schema/jobs/627323874#L855 twine fails as empty value are passed (this is not an issue in my local machine).
The variables are supposedly exported at the start of the build (https://app.travis-ci.com/github/blockchain-certificates/cert-schema/jobs/627323874#L180-L181), and I have just set the variables' name and value again in the settings, so I know for sure they are not empty there.
Here the script intent:
echo $TWINE_USERNAME
echo $TWINE_PASSWORD
twine upload dist/* -u $TWINE_USERNAME -p $TWINE_PASSWORD --verbose

And I have changed the execution of the script from sh to . as I read the context would be preserved, but to no avail.
Can someone help me there?

Create a [mcve] then show it in a question (no images no links, just text) so we can help you.

The issue was with semantic-release (python) which didn't handle Twine uploads anymore.
I removed the the release-package script from semantic-release flow and added as an independent step after semantic-release version instruction.
The script is now executed within the correct context and picks up global variables.
